# Is there a way to invoke own version of node.js on Node startup?

Tags: node.js

I just started playing with node debugger and noticed a [node.js file](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.js) which is invoked at the very beginning of node execution.

As the comment in the file says

> This file is invoked by node::Load in src/node.cc, and responsible for bootstrapping the node.js core.

I'd like to change content of this file to something else (yes, I know there's no need to do that), **is there a way to replace content of that file / specify path to new file without compiling node from source**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Nope.

If I read the source correctly, the file *node.js* gets compiled into the resulting binary, as a string - the file itself does not exist anywhere on the filesystem so you cannot modify it and, for the same reason, you cannot tell Node to execute your own version of it.

Best look at the sources - mainly the [LoadEnvironment](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.cc#L2809) method.